# Replace href's for elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How can I replace href's for all link's including elements link within a nb-repeat.

I retrieve data from external api's with links in them (`<a href=".."></a>`),
witch I add to a controller scope, and let angular fill out a repeat-list,
but I need to replace the actual link with a custom directive.

A solution could be to do replacement href before the controller compiles,
but I cannot find any kind of pre-compiling for a controller (only for directive)

Currently I have this solution, which works if I compile the content I retrieve,

```
elm.html(content); replaceAHrefs(elm); $compile(elm.contents())(scope)
```

but because the retrieved content also contains directives and controllers,
I cannot do that because the compiling of the controller triggers its init method twice (which is not acceptable!) and I don't have control of it anyway!

```
function replaceAHrefs(elm) {
    var atags = elm.find('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < atags.length; i += 1) {
        var atag = angular.element(atags[i]);
        var href = atag.attr('href');
        var ngHref = atag.attr('ng-href');
        var dontReplace = atag.attr("dont-replace-href");
        console.log(atags[i],atag,href,ngHref,dontReplace);
        if ((ngHref || href) && isSelfServiceLink(href) && dontReplace === undefined) {
            atag.attr('ng-click', 'takeOverLink($event)');
            $compile(atag)(atag.scope());
        }
    }
}
```

SO:

How can I altar the html before angular compiles the controller?

Any other suggestions? :-)

(Again, please to say something like, you should do this in the temple, or use ng-href, because I don't have control over the content that i retrieve)

---

An example of a href (and ng-href) that I need to replace is something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-controller="HtmlContentLoadedThatICannotChangeBeforeAfterDomLoad">
    <h2>Title..</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="service in services | orderBy:'name'">
        <a href='SomeLinkThatIWillReplaceWithADirective'>service.label</a>
        <a ng-href='{{AnotherLinkThatIWillReplaceWithADirective}}'>service.label</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can we have the ng-repeat block, along with the href

Comment: show us your ng-repeat block

Comment: I have added an example of some content where I need to takeover the href. I cannot change the html before load time, so again some kind of PreCompiling of the inner Controller will fix my problem..